# mysql - trigger table change

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I want to trigger an alert on screen when some changes made to my `mysql` tables using PHP.

Currently, I have many tables with different structures (Purchase Order, Sales Order, Users etc), my intention is  to make a real-time application, but the problem is that I have already written 90% of the application.

I have a table with name `activity`
It Contains:

`id, table, action, dateTime, user`

When some changes are made to `Purchase Order` table, then I need to log

`(0,'TABLE A','INSERT','12/12/12','John')`

so that I can show `JOHN created a new Purchase Order`.

Please note that I have already written many parts of the application, what will be the most possible way to achieve this ?

Comment: Create a new table, EVENTS, store all the CRUD events of the Database in the EVENTS table, use LONG POLLING or Web Sockets to get the latest EVENT occurred.

Comment: Above suggestion will need a bit of work (more triggers). You may try to create a daemon that will keep running and will read and store the new Inserts in specified tables.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , the problem is that i need to collect the data first , i already wrote the application , i was expecting independent way to achieve this with out making many changes to the existing source code.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was suggesting the Daemon Method (comment#2)
The Daemon will run on specified Tables of the Database and will just keep information of last read rows and in next run update that information. That info then can be passed on to UI with WebSockets. This will be a totally independent module, won't require changes in your application

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to log changes in *activity* table then you can create triggers on every table (orders, sales, users etc) that you want to monitor like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_orders_insert` AFTER INSERT ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `table`, `action`, `date_time`, `user`) VALUES (NEW.id, 'orders', 'insert', NOW(), 'user1')  

CREATE TRIGGER `tg_orders_update` AFTER UPDATE ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `table`, `action`, `date_time`, `user`) VALUES (NEW.id, 'orders', 'update', NOW(), 'user1')  

CREATE TRIGGER `tg_orders_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `table`, `action`, `date_time`, `user`) VALUES (OLD.id, 'orders', 'delete', NOW(), 'user1')
```